How to verify the general linear group on a finite field is a BN-pair?
This is an exercise from textbook GTM 162 (Groups and Representation).
Let $G=GL(n,q)$ be the general linear group over a finite field F, where F is a finite field with $q$ elements. Let $B$ be the standard Borel subgroup of G, that is, all of the upper triangular matrices, let $N$ be the subgroup consisting of all monomial matrices(each row and column has exactly one non-zero entry), and let $T=B\cap N$.
We can regard $W = N/T$ as being imbedded in G as the group of permutation
matrices.Let S be the subset of $W$ consisting
of those permutation matrices that are obtained from the identity
matrix by switching two adjacent columns. (In other words, if we
identify $W$ with $\Sigma _n$, then S corresponds to the
set $\{(1 2), (23), ... ,(n-1 \hspace{2mm} n)\}$.)
And I have successfully verified all the conditions required by the tits-system axioms, except the following one.
For any $s \in S$ and $w \in W$. How prove that
$$ sBw \subseteq BwB \cup BswB
$$
?
I have made some attempts based on the Bruhat decomposition theorem, letting $s$ be the matrix determined by transposition (i j) and taking the matrix $sbw \in sBw$, I can prove that $sbw$ will belong to $BswB$ if the (i,j) element of $b$ is $0$, but I am at a loss for the non-zero case.
